# python 3 - mac address based on ip - scapy

Tags: python, networking, ip, scapy, mac-address

i am working on a way to obtain the mac address of a machine based on its ip, therefore i use python in combination with scapy:

```
def obtain_mac(IP):
        conf.verb = 0
        ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst = IP), timeout = 2, iface = interface, retry = 10)
        for snd,rcv in ans:
            return rcv.sprintf(r"%Ether.src%")
            # i also tried this, but same result
            #return rcv[Ether].src
```

When i run this method:

```
try:
        otherMac = obtain_mac(192.168.2.134)
except Exception:
        # some stuff
        print ("[!] Couldn't Find MAC Address")
        sys.exit(1)
```

it always returns:

```
Couldn't Find MAC Address
```

I am running this code from my linux.
Using ping i already made sure, that i can access the other machine in network.

is there anything i missed from docs?

thanks and greetings

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: well, is the api gone? or why cant i get mac addres from ip ?

Comment: I would try to get the MAC by looking at the `ARP-Table`, take a look [here](http://python-arptable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html). The `ARP-Table` "translates" IP-Adresses to MAC

Comment: this library is for python 2

Comment: You can just call `arp -a` and parse the output...

Comment: Are you trying this against a host on the same network? You cannot get the MAC address of a host on a different network.

Answer (score 0):

First, try

```
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

or better

`logger.exception(e)`

to see the error details, next try run as root.